# How to insert the result of evaluating a sexp in a string?

Tags: string, format

I am new to Emacs and I am reading Elisp guide inside Emacs. I am at the *Args as Variable or list* chapter. There is listed below code-

```lisp
    (concat "The " (number-to-string (+ 2 value)) "red foxes.")
```

`value` here is an integer set by some function.

Now I want to print `fox` instead of `foxes` if the list argument to the concat function returns 1. How can I do that?

Comment: You are using `+ 2`, so unless `fill-column` is `-1` I don't see how you can get `1` out of that `(+ 2 fill-column)`. `C-h v fill-column RET` on `emacs -Q` gives me `70`, for instance.

Comment: @manuel-uberti I edited my question

Comment: Thank you, I updated my answer as well.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `format` instead of `concat`. For example:

```
(let* ((n (+ 2 value))
       (f (if (= 1 n) "fox" "foxes")))
  (format "The %d red %s" n f))
```

You can check the documentation of `format` (<kbd>C-h f format RET</kbd>) to understand the meaning of `%d` and `%s` and know more about this function. Check also <kbd>C-h f let* RET</kbd> to know more about let bindings.

Comment: FWIW, since Emacs 27 there's also the function `ngettext` for picking between singular/plural, although it's currently an English-specific no-op :)

Comment: This worked, but I think I have to study more to understand this code(let*). Thanks for follow up for documentation as well.